# Catching errors from mongoose queries in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

How can I catch error from mongoose queries. In my routes I got something like this:

```
// router.js
router.route('/signup')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var profile = new Profile(); // create a new instance of the profile model
        profile.username    = req.body.username;
        profile.password    = profile.generateHash(req.body.password);
        profile.save(function(err) {
            if (err) { // (A)
                throw new Error('user/create error'));
            } else {
                res.json(200, { user_token: profile._id, username: profile.username }); 
            }
        });
    });
```

and in my app were I set up my routes I got this:

```
// app.js
var router = require('./app/routes/routes'); 
// global-error handling middleware
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('Some error is happening.');
    res.json(500, {status: 500, message: err.message});

});
```

If I generate a error so I get to line // (A) in my code above I get a stack trace and node.js exists. I want to catch the error In my error handler. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are already in the request handler, and you already have access to the error produced while saving the profile object. So, there is no need to throw an exception here. You can *already* handle the problem.

The most likely scenario here is to send a response to the user indicating that the saving of the profile failed.

```
function(req, res) {
   profile.save(function(err) {
      if (err) { // (A)
        res.send(500, {message: 'Failed to save profile'}
      } else {
         res.json(200, { user_token: profile._id, username: profile.username }); 
      }
  });
}
```

And that's it. Your client will receive a 500 status error and this evidently represents a problem that your client will need to deal with, like notifying the user, doing a retry, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is what I does most of the time. But if the mongo database have crashed I dont get into function(err) { if (err) {... It just skips the whole profile.save(...) call. I want to respond with an error even if the database is down.

Comment: Turns out I was missing the `else` and my app was going down because of a `hearder already sent` error, not because of the insertion.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Promise-like error handling. mongoose permits to use promises on its methods:

```
profile.save().then((doc) => {
        // if done correctly
}).catch((err) => {
    // catch error if occurs
    // handle error
});
```

- you can read more about mongoose built-in promises [there](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

Comment: Is this syntax correct? Shouldn't there be a then() or a try?